# Odd method behavior - ToString of a function

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Consider this code snippet:

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
   Console.WriteLine(Test().ToString());
  }

  static IEnumerable<char> Test() {
   foreach (var ch in "test")
    yield return ch;
  }
  static IEnumerable<char> TestOk() {
   return "test";
  }
 }
```

`Test().ToString()` returns "ConsoleApplication1.Program+d__0" instead of expected "test".

`Test()` method isn't even executed - just returns its name! The second method `TestOk()` works just fine.

What is going on?

Comment: You sure you didn't do Test.ToString() instead of Test().ToString()? This should print "IEnumerable" not what it printed.

Comment: @Jouke - It takes 30 seconds to try it and see for yourself - the output is exactly as stated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's printing the ToString method on the IEnumerable implementation generated by the compiler - Iterators are just syntactic sugar - a real implementation of IEnumerable is generated.

Comment: Ok, but there's a way to actually execute this method and get the expected string ("test")?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is the expected result. The result is an enumerable that returns each character in "test". You can build a string out of it by iterating over it and concatenating the characters.

Comment: Ok. `Test().ToArray()` do the job.

Answer (score 2):

The Test() method returns an IEnumerable(char) which in this case is a compiler generated object. It's ToString() method is the default for an object and returns the type name, also compiler generated.

Answer (score 2):

The yeild return method is treated differently be the compiler - if you check the compiled assembly using reflector whats going on here becomes a little clearer:

```
private static IEnumerable<char> Test()
{
    return new <Test>d__0(-2);
}
```

Wheras `TestOk` returns a string, `Test` instead returns a class that the compiler generates for you.  What you are seeing is the default string representation of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have explained the current behavior, but if you want to get your expected behavior then instead of using ToString() you can convert the `IEnumerable<char>` to an array and use the String constructor that takes a `char[]`:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(Test().ToArray()));
```