# List<string[]> displaying list values

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code that generates a `List<string[]>` variable but can't quite figure out how to get it to display in a text box properly.

```
List<string[]> test = parseCSV();
for (int i = 0;  i < test.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("i = {0}",i);
  Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", test[i]);
  nameList.Text = test[i].ToString() + "\n" + nameList.Text;
}
```

When I output `test[i]` to the console it displays the string information correctly, but when I output `test[i]` to a text box I get:

```
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common misconception with `ToString` that shows up in a [variety of situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483745/odd-method-behavior-tostring-of-a-function). It is not a magical formatting wizard, even if primitive types appear to work "as you expect". ToString simply provides a reasonable representation of the data at hand.

In the case of array data, it would be obnoxious and likely incorrect for .Net to output the entire array for every ToString call (which the debugger makes heavy usage of). Imagine a 3D array of strings that is 60x60x10. I would hate to have to wait on that to get rendered simply because I put my mouse over an array in the debugger.

In this case you could use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
for (int i = 0;  i < test.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("i = {0}",i);
    Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", test[i]);
    nameList.Text = String.Join(", ", test[i]) + "\n" + nameList.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`test[i]` is a string array. Arrays don't override `ToString()`, so you're just getting the default implementation, which shows the type of the object (`System.String[]` in this case).

It's not clear what you *wanted* to do with it. For example, you could use:

```
Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", string.Join(", ", test[i]));
```

... to create a comma-separated string from all the strings within the array.

EDIT: Note that this:

```
Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", test[i]);
```

is actually printing out the *first* string from each string array. It's using array covariance to convert the `string[]` to `object[]`. To perform the same operation more clearly, you'd use:

```
Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", test[i][0]);
```

So if you *want* to just get the first value from each array into the textbox, you could use:

```
nameList.Text = test[i][0] + "\r\n" + nameList.Text;
```

(Note that this will effectively reverse the order of the "rows".) I've changed `\n` to `\r\n` as that's what text boxes use for line breaks on Windows.)

Comment: Console.WriteLine("test[i] = {0}", test[i]); Does exactly what I want it to do, it outputs each string element as a new line, no commas.

Comment: nameList.Text = test[i].ToString() + "\n" + nameList.Text; Is the problem, I cant get it to display in the textbox the same way it does in the console, using the same code?

Comment: @user1296932: No, it doesn't. That outputs the *first* string from each array.

Comment: @user1296932: See my edit - if you *really* just want the first value from each array, you want `test[i][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing arrays of strings in your list. The correct code would be:

```
foreach (string[] items in test)
   foreach (string item in items)
   {
       ...
   }
```

This iterates over all the arrays in your list and then over all the items in the current array.

Answer (score 0):

yo are using ToString() method on test[i].ToString() please use it like this test[i]

For your knowledge Object.ToString() Returns a string that represents the current object.

Hence you get

```
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
System.String[]
```